# downcast to multiple inheritance undefined behavior?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting

I have multiple calculation units each operate its own data, and I have some requirement to combine all these data into one object vector. So I created the following template:

```
 template <class D1 = Dummy<1>, class D2 = Dummy<2>, class D3 = Dummy<3>, class D4 = Dummy<4>, class D5 = Dummy<5>, class D6 = Dummy<6> >
struct GroupData : public GenericType, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6 {
        GroupData() : GenericType(), D1(), D2(), D3(), D4(), D5(), D6() {}

        template <class T>
        T& Get() {
                T* result = static_cast<T*>(this);
                if (!result) PLOGL("GroupData Bad cast!");
                return *(result);
        }
};
```

And then I have:

```
std::vector<GenericType*> dataSet;
typedef GroupData<C1, C2, C3, C4> MyData;
dataSet.push_back(new MyData);
```

When I need to access it:

```
C1& c1 = static_cast<MyData*>(dataSet[0])->Get<C1>();
```

What I noticed is that when I'd modify GroupData definition to have 11 arguments, things start getting strange.
The calculation on data shows strange results although all inputs seem fine but it doesn't always happen across different builds or optimization level.
I'm using g++4.1.2 on redhat 5.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Comment: If I first check for MyData* == NULL, everything works fine and it's never NULL.